# how do i keep my goldfish tank's bottom clean?

Tags: fish, community-aquarium, goldfish, cleaning

my goldfish tank's water is crystal clear and the filter is working fine but goldfish creates a lot of waste so their manure collects on the bottom of the tank(which is bare), is it okay or will it create ammonia spikes? I know that you can siphon out the poop but then you will be doing that every other day, is there any alternatives to this?

btw my tank is a 40 gal with 2 goldfish and 2 pangasius(and 2 red neon lobsters), I'm planning to add more...

Comment: You need to control your water values regularly anyway, so there's no need for speculation whether you filter can handle it. A lot of bacteria lives in the gravel as well and it makes the habitat appear more natural. The amount of waste is proportional to the amount of food. Check the linked answer for more advise.

Answer (score 0):

Frequent water changes are necessary, no matter what you do. You could get an under-gravel filter and some gravel, which will hide the poop, but not get rid of the ammonia, nitrites, and nitrates. The water will eventually become toxic.

Take a look at https://www.thesprucepets.com/water-changes-1381886 for more information.

Short version, change out 15-20% of your tank's water weekly with dechlorinated (https://www.aqueon.com/products/specialty-equipment/siphon-vacuum-gravel-cleaners) water. A great way to do this is using a gravel siphon (https://www.aqueon.com/products/specialty-equipment/siphon-vacuum-gravel-cleaners). That will help you get the water and the poop out at the same time.